# Loop with conditional in ansible

Tags: ansible, keycloak, ansible-template

I have a keycloak realm template in ansible and want to load array of values from that template.

My template file looks something like this:

```
 {
 // Some json here
  "roles": {
     "client": {
         "demo-app": [
         {
           "name": "Administrator",
           "composite": true,
           "composites": {
             "client": {
               "realm-management": [
                 "view-users",
                 "manage-identity-providers",
                 "query-clients",
                 "query-users",
               ]
             }
           },
           "clientRole": true,
         },
         {   
           "name": "Developer",
           "composite": false,
           "clientRole": true,
         },
         {
           "name": "Operator",
           "composite": false,
           "clientRole": true,
         }
      ],
     }
  }
}
```

Now I want to read realm-management array values from the template. For that, I have written task in ansible. It goes as below:

```
- name: 'Ensure realm-management roles are added to demo-app "Administrator" role'
   debug:
     msg: "{{ item }}"
   loop: "{{ lookup('template', 'realm/DemoRealm-realm.json.j2').roles.client['demo-app'] }} | subelements('composites.client.realm-management') }}"
   when:
     - item.name == 'Administrator'
     - item.composite == true
     - item.composites is defined
```

My expectation is to print values from `realm-management` array. But the task I have added is also looping through `Developer` and `Operator` objects ignoring conditional and as they don't have `composites` key in them, task is failing. I have tried numerous approaches but none worked. Please suggest me what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json_query` to validate object properties like so:

```
 loop: "{{ lookup('template', 'realm/DemoRealm-realm.json.j2').roles.client['demo-app'] | json_query('[?name==`Administrator` && composite==`true` && composites]') }}"
```

when: item.composites is defined"

Comment: Thank you so much!! Solution you suggested was returning only 'Administrator' object which I exactly needed .  I added subelements to retrieve only realm-management array instead of whole object.

`debug:
  msg: "{{ item.1 }}"
loop: "{{ lookup('template', 'realm/DemoRealm-realm.json.j2').roles.client['demo-app'] | json_query('[?name=='Administrator' && composite=='true' && composites]') | subelements('composites.client.realm-management') }}"`

Comment: @Varun, can you select my answer as accepted if you like that is.